C++ Python Package creates a function with Pass
I am trying to create a python package from C++ code. I have all the desired functionality in C++ and a setup.py file. Running the setup.py works fine and creates the package, however when I go to actually run the function or look at the code, the end code is just a defined function with a Pass in it. It doesn't look like the C++ code is being ported.
Setup.py
from setuptools import setup, Extension

# Define the extension module
fuzzyDic_module = Extension('fuzzyDic',
                            sources=['src/fuzzyDict.cpp', 'src/pyConversion.cpp'],
                            include_dirs=['src'])

# Setup
setup(name='fuzzyDic',
      version='1.2',
      description='A Python module for fuzzy string search of single dict or list of dict',
      ext_modules=[fuzzyDic_module])


And the output is:
def fuzzyDic(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """ Perform fuzzy search """
    pass

Because of the huge pain of debugging with Python and C++ simultaneously, I think my next step is to re-write some of the logic to work in C++ and step through it to see where it fails. I was going to do this anyways, but figured I would test the build process where I am at now to see.

It's not clear what do you mean by the output. Did you run python setup.py build that should produce a dynamic library which can be imported in python? How do you export your C++ xxx fuzzyDic(yyy) function to python? Pybind11, Cython, Boost::Python? At least you need to provide (minimal) content of your cpp sources.
